# Command for syncing a file from local computer to a remote server in Java - WinSCP

Tags: java, cmd, winscp

I'm trying to automate a file synchronisation from a local computer to a remote host in java using WinSCP. Can someone help me suggest what would be the command?

```
          //---Javacode
          Runtime.getRunTime().exe(cmd /...../);
```

Comment: Why can't you use WinSCP's own scripting language.

Comment: I think you might find `rsync` to be very useful for accomplishing your goal. Unless this is just an exercise for using java in which case I'd go with the answer for using jsch.

Comment: @GarrettHall I was trying to sync a file which is generated by a program that runs in while loop as long as it receives data. I need to update the server live with the new data. So I'm tryign to add in the command for WinSCP, so that everytime i close the file I can sync it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't exec().  Use either the ant scp task which will do the same thing as WinSCP, or directly integrate JSCH:

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Much simpler.

Comment: You could also use commons-vfs which will shield the details of jsch from you, as it has an sftp: protocol.  http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html#SFTP

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP command-line to synchronize file is like:

```
winscp.com /command ^
    "option batch abort" ^
    "open sftp://username@example.com" ^
    "synchronize d:\www\ ./www/" ^
    "exit"
```

See the [guide to WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).